# Jquery-ui Auto complete not working properly

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to display an auto complete text box. I'm also trying to display the city names and wanna store the corresponding `cityId` of the city in another box while selecting one city.The auto complete box is  working fine(I mean I'm getting the city name list).But when I select a city, its name is not showing in the box but it shows the id.
My code is given below.

```
 <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="txtCity"  placeholder="City" id="txtCity" class="form-control">
          <input type="text" name="txtCityId"  placeholder="City" id="txtCityId" class="form-control">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $("#txtCity").autocomplete({
  source: 'getcitylist',
  select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#txtCity").html(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
       // $("#txtCityId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

This is the data base function:

```
 public function getCityList(){
            $term = Input::get('term');
            $cityList = CityModel::getCityNameAjax($term);
            foreach ($cityList  as $key=>$value) {  
                $data[$key]['label']=$value->cityName;
                $data[$key]['value']=$value->id;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/805/ works well for me.

Comment: That's not working. when you select 'always' it do not shows 'always' (label) in the text box instead it shows '1'(value). the same issue i'm facing in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent default methods of setting value with `event.preventDefault()` or you can return `false` also.

Complete code:

```
$( "#textCity" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault(); //preventing default methods
        $("#textCity").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#textCityId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
    }
});
```

Working demo link:
http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/806/